# ngReact give "Error: module 'react' not found from ...ngReact.min.js" in browserify, angular project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, reactjs, browserify

I am trying to include react in an existing AngularJS project. Found a bower package called ngReact. I added this and react to my project using browserify. Running grunt just give me `"Error: module 'react' not found from ..../bower_components/ngReact/ngReact.min.js"`

Any ideas?

In my *angular-app.js*

```
'use strict';
var di = require('di');
var angular = require('angular');
require('angular-resource');
require('angular-route');
require('bootstrap');
require('angular-bootstrap');
...
require('react');
require('ngReact');
```

In my *package.json*

```
"browser":{
    "jquery": "./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "angular": "./bower_components/angular/angular.js",
    "bootstrap": "./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "angular-resource": "./bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js",
    "angular-route": "./bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js",
    "angular-bootstrap": "./bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-
    ...
    "react": "./bower_components/react/react.js",
    "ngReact": "./bower_components/ngReact/ngReact.min.js"
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you use npm components instead of bower?

Comment: I like npm a lot and use it in many different projects. This project has got everything in place using bower... However, I acually don't really see why it uses bower since the seed it is based on does not: https://github.com/btford/angular-express-blog

Comment: if you want to use browserify you need to use npm! browserify uses commonjs-style modules. npm modules are based on commonjs-syntax, bower not!

Comment: @hereandnow78, it's not true. For example, jQuery can be used as commonjs library. bower or npm, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @dizel3d: that's only because jQuery does it that way (and a few other libraries too), but it's NOT a must for libraries published through bower to do stuff like this. there isn't a general convention for bower modules on how to handle this. if your bower-included lib just doesn't support commonjs syntax, browserify WILL NOT WORK, and that's why it DOES MATTER! you can of course install libs via bower which support commonjs and the other libs throught npm, or even shim bower-libs, but in general i would recommend to use npm, just because it will be the frontend-packagemanager of the future!